# It looks like underwater ice disappeared rather than melting, is it normal?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I got 8t of ice with care packages. I put it at the bottom of my water reserve, expecting it to melt directly in it when defrosting.

Yet, when I came back after, the temperature was getting higher. I didn't find the ice anymore but it looks like it didn't fill my reservoir (the "available water" amount displayed at the pump didn't seem to change much. Even though I can't exclude to be misunderstanding the way it works (does it display the amount in the block(s)? Directly bellow it? Or does it display the quantity in the whole reservoir?)

Is it a bug or did I get something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Two things are worth noting here:

1. Any tile that contains water will only contain water, i.e. not mix with gases or other liquids, and house up to 1 ton (1000kg) of water per tile outside of cases with pressured storage.
2. The pitcher pump's "available water" tooltip indicates how much water is within tiles it can actually reach, which is the 2x5 area below the actual pitcher (though varies with obstruction).

Those things considered, if you have a particularly wide pool of water, the ice most likely melted and the water was distributed along the pools top layer, and you wouldn't notice, as an increase from for example 500kg to 700kg of water per surface tile wouldn't actually have any effect on which tiles the water occupies. In this example, your pitcher pump's "available water" tooltip would increase by 400kg since it would only consider the change to the two top-most water tiles regardless of how wide the pool is.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'll provide a screen of my pool when I'll be home.
From memory my pool is around 8-10 tiles wide, but it's not as deep as long as the pitcher can be.
I don't get the "400kg" increase tho. Wouldn't it depend on how wide my pool is ?

Comment: My bad. If you add 8000kg to a 10-wide pool, that's 800kg added to each surface tile. Since the pitcher only reads tiles it is in contact with, that'd be 2 of the 10 surface tiles, meaning it's "liquid available" would increase by 1600kg.